# PHP image width not responding?

Tags: php, mysql, css, image

I have this code so I can set a minimum width and it does not work? I have tried and it doesn't want to do anything ... is there something with my if logic ?

```
$imagesize = getimagesize($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']);
$width = $imagesize[0];
if($width>500)
{
    $error_msg="too small";
    print($error_msg);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Looks like your if comparison is backwards.  Try: `if($width<500)`

Comment: What is the output ? If its blank, enable error reporting in php.ini and check the output.

Comment: Too small for greater than 500?

Comment: `>500` = "greater than 500"

Comment: wow lol i didnt see that ... how would i get the height now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to filter out small images, you should reverse the comparison to `if($width<500)`. In addition to all this, in the future, you can always add extra debug statements across several lines to help you figure out the path your code is taking. Just some `echo` statements along the way will do.

Retrieving the height will just be `$height = $imagesize[1];`

You can find more about the `$imagesize` variable you created by printing its contents: `print_r($imagesize);`

Answer (score 0):

Switch your IF statement to:

```
if($width<500)
{
    $error_msg="too small";
    print($error_msg);
    exit();
}
```

Also, see what it says about the image size by printing out that variable:

```
print_r($imagesize);
```